# 'fatal: Not a git repository' is prompted when execute make command in Geocouch folder on Ubuntu

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

My purpose is to extend couchDB with geocouch, then i download COUchDB src from http://couchdb.apache.org/,and geocouch from github [couchdb 1.2.x](https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch/tree/couchdb1.2.x). the src are both in my Download path,according to the instruction in Readme file.I do in below steps:

```
ryu@ryu-Asp:~/Downloads$ cd geocouch-couchdb1.2.x/
export COUCH_SRC=/home/ryu/Downloads/apache-couchdb-1.2.1/src/couchdb/
make
```

after i enter make command, it pop up below error message:

```
ryu@ryu-Asp:~/Downloads/geocouch-couchdb1.2.x$ make
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
ERL_COMPILER_OPTIONS='[{i,"/home/ryu/Downloads/apache-couchdb-1.2.1/src/couchdb/"}]' ./rebar compile
==> geocouch-couchdb1.2.x (compile)
Compiled src/geocouch/couch_spatial_compactor.erl
Compiled src/geocouch/geocouch_duplicates.erl
Compiled src/geocouch/couch_httpd_spatial.erl
Compiled src/geocouch/couch_httpd_spatial_list.erl
Compiled src/geocouch/couch_spatial.erl
Compiled src/vtree/run_vtreestats.erl
Compiled src/vtree/vtreeviz.erl
Compiled src/geocouch/couch_spatial_updater.erl
Compiled src/vtree/vtreestats.erl
Compiled src/vtree/run_vtreeviz.erl
Compiled src/geocouch/couch_spatial_group.erl
Compiled src/vtree/vtree_insbench.erl
Compiled test/gc_test_util.erl
Compiled src/vtree/vtree.erl
Compiled src/vtree/vtree_bulk.erl
Compiled src/vtree/vtree_bulk.erl
```

Btw, i had tried to combine apache-couchdb-1.1.1 with geocouch-couchdb1.1.x as well, but still got the same 'fatal error message', this issue really exhaust me, it have waste me too many time. any tip will be appreciated..

Comment: Are you sure it is mandatory? Isn't it just to get the last revision?

Comment: at last i found it is not a must. just skip this issue and it still work well with couchDB. perhaps i feel uncomfortable if there is any issue popped up. but thanks anyway.

Comment: Nice to know it's a non issue. You should close the question then.

Comment: I am sorry i still not familiar with this forum, I think it should be over now, Do i need other extra operation to close this issue?

Comment: Ah, I thought you had a close button. Then I will post my past comment so that you can accept it as the answer if you want ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I suppose it's not mandatory. It is probably only needed to update the sources to the last revision.